# Hive : finding items that customers bought together from transactions

Tags: mysql, hive

I am working on mysql but need to replicate some queries on hive.

I have a table in this form

[image: transaction table]

I would like to retrieve the following info:

[image: Resultant table]

On mysql, the below query works:

```
SELECT c.original_item_id, c.bought_with_item_id, count(*) as times_bought_together
FROM (
  SELECT a.item_id as original_item_id, b.item_id as bought_with_item_id
  FROM items a
  INNER join items b
  ON a.transaction_id = b.transaction_id AND a.item_id != b.item_id where original_item_id in ('B','C')) c
GROUP BY c.original_item_id, c.bought_with_item_id;
```

But I am not able to translate this to a hive query, I have tried lot of shuffling joins and replacing where with on conditions but have not got the necessary results. Would be great if I can find some help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive does not support not equality joins. But you can move this condition  `a.item_id != b.item_id` into `where` clause:

```
create table items(transaction_id smallint, item_id string);

insert overwrite table items 
select 1 , 'A'  from default.dual union all
select 1 , 'B'  from default.dual union all
select 1 , 'C'  from default.dual union all
select 2 , 'B'  from default.dual union all
select 2 , 'A'  from default.dual union all
select 3 , 'A'  from default.dual union all
select 4 , 'B'  from default.dual union all
select 4 , 'C'  from default.dual;

SELECT c.original_item_id, c.bought_with_item_id, count(*) as times_bought_together
FROM (
      SELECT a.item_id as original_item_id, b.item_id as bought_with_item_id
      FROM items a
      INNER join items b ON a.transaction_id = b.transaction_id 
      WHERE 
            a.item_id in ('B','C') --original_item_id
        and a.item_id != b.item_id   
     ) c
GROUP BY c.original_item_id, c.bought_with_item_id;
---
OK
original_item_id        bought_with_item_id     times_bought_together
B       A       2
B       C       2
C       A       1
C       B       2
```

Time taken: 24.164 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)